# How to use android device as Computer Mouse?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app which will act as the mouse of computer. So how to start please suggest.
Just want to mimic the mouse movement using Android screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using your real computer mouse and observe its behavior.
Then mimic that behavior in your application.

Comment: I have done this but my problem is that the mouse pointer is moving as per the screen size of android phone.

Comment: If you have laptop then observe its behavior. If the touchpad ends and you click the touchpad on different coordinates then also  the pointer maintain its location on the screen and starts moving from their. So how to achieve this on android screen.